# python open a .xls file one a smb server

Tags: python, excel, file, tkinter, command

I am learning python.
I would like to code a little helper in tkinter that has some buttons related to functions that open some files I need everyday for my work.

Tose files are all located on our company server.

This is what I tried so far without any result (example, x in ip gets of course replaced by real digit)):

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os
import threading
import openpyxl


app = Tk()
app.geometry('500x500')
app.title('workplace')


def Versch():
    file = openpyxl.load_workbook('smb//192.xxx.x.xx/share/12 Verschiffungen/Verschiffungen Kontrolle.xlsx')


b_Verschiff = ttk.Button(app,text='Verschiff', command=Versch)
b_Verschiff.pack()



app.mainloop()
```

I just want to click the button, and open the .xlsx file (not in python terminal, the real file)

Comment: Better to mount the SMB share to a folder and access the file under the mounted folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `subprocess`. Just change your function to:

```
import subprocess
.....

def Versch():
    filename = 'smb://192.xxx.x.xx/share/12 Verschiffungen/Verschiffungen Kontrolle.xlsx')
    subprocess.call(['open', filename])
```

This will do the job for MAC, for windows, you would use `os`. Like,

```
import os
....

os.startfile('smb://192.xxx.x.xx/share/12 Verschiffungen/Verschiffungen Kontrolle.xlsx')
```

Hope this helped you out. Do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: @exec85 Im sorry for the foolishness ive updated the answer xp

Comment: Should it be `smb://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/...` (`:` after `smb`)?

Comment: it is opening the directory, but seems to not wanna open the actual file then. 
It just stays in the directory.